# Promises not running with Mocha, in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, bluebird

I have some code which makes use of promises, but it fails to run when run through Mocha. I have simplified it to the essentials:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const Promise = require('bluebird');

console.log('zzzz IN');
Promise.resolve('xxx').then(function(val) {
    console.log('[normal]', val);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('[error]', error);

})
console.log('zzzz OUT');
```

when run via `node test/index.js` I get:

```
zzzz IN
zzzz OUT
[normal] xxx
```

but via mocha:

```
> my-server@0.0.1 test /Users/ajmas/Development/mocha-and-promise
> eslint lib && mocha --timeout 10000

zzzz IN
zzzz OUT


0 passing (0ms)
```

Is this an issue in Mocha or in the way I have configured things?

Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-server",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Mocha and Promises test case",
    "main": "lib/main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start-dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node test/index.js",
        "start-dev-debug": "DEBUG=express:* npm run start-dev",
        "start": "node lib/main.js",
        "test": "eslint lib && mocha --timeout 10000"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.7.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bluebird": "^3.4.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
        "eslint": "^3.8.1",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
        "mocha": "^3.2.0"
    }
}
```

Running with node 6.7.0 on MacOS X 10.12.2. Have also tried with '[bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)', '[promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise)' and native Promise, but same behaviour with each.

BTW this code is meant to be part of the application I am integration testing, but because no promises  are completing I can't launch the server from within Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it works, but you need to put the code with an 'it' function call, such that:

```
it('Run the promise', function(done) {
    Promise.resolve('xxx').then(function(val) {
        console.log('[normal]', val);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('[error]', error);
    })
})
```

Comment: You don't need `done`, you can simply return the Promise. See https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises